# Is there a way a cast the parameter of a closure?

Tags: groovy, closures

I'm a long time java user, however I'm playing around with groovy for the first time.  I'm trying to re-create try-with-resources by using .withCloseable(Closure).

This works for me, however, I'm curious if there's a way to eliminate the additional statement to just perform a cast.

```
new MyCloseable().withCloseable { closeable ->
    def myCloseable = (MyCloseable) closeable;
    ...
}
```

If I try to invoke a method of MyCloseable without that explicit cast, I get

```
No such property: MyCloseable for class: com.test.MyTest
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: MyCloseable for class: com.test.MyTest
```

Comment: Just remove it? It shouldn't be necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necessary or not, of course you can define the data type of a closure parameter:

```
def list = [1, 2, 3]
list.each { float i ->
    println i
}
```

prints

```
1.0
2.0
3.0
```

So in your case it would be

```
new MyCloseable().withCloseable { MyCloseable closeable ->
    ...
}
```

Comment: This did it!  Closures are a bit funky feeling for me still so I was trying to use cast syntax `(MyCloseable) closeable ->`instead of just declaring the type of the parameter like you did!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've prepared several options for you:

```
new MyCloseable().withCloseable { closeable ->
    MyCloseable myCloseable = closeable
    ...
}

new MyCloseable().withCloseable { MyCloseable closeable ->
    def myCloseable = closeable
    ...
}

new MyCloseable().withCloseable { closeable ->
    def myCloseable = closeable as MyCloseable
    ...
}
```

Try the groovier! :)